# Multiple users reviewing the same suggested edit

Tags: support

Some suggested edits are quite long to read through and sometimes I may try to improve on a suggested edit. This all takes time.

I began wondering what would happen if another user was reviewing a suggested edit at the same time as me. Does the suggested edit get 'locked' whilst I'm reviewing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it doesn't get locked.  Suggested edit reviews are first come, first serve, however, there is a minor exception that lets you continue improve edits that are approved while you are reviewing, it won't change the result of the review.